# Checkk if Apple Watch is connected (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchos, watchconnectivity

I have made an application for iOS device to get the heart rate data continuously from the watch. It is working as intended and I wanted to add a test case checking if the watch is connected (paired) with the device. My code for testing it is:

```
if WCSession.isSupported() {
    let wcsession = WCSession.default
    wcsession.delegate = self as? WCSessionDelegate
    wcsession.activate()
    if(wcsession.isPaired){
        print("paired")
    }else{
        print("not paired")
    }
}
```

However, I get an error:

`2020-02-29 15:25:55.044843+0900 HeartRateApp[68975:11196372] [WC] denying activation due to missing delegate
2020-02-29 15:25:55.044969+0900 HeartRateApp[68975:11196372] [WC] WCSession has not been activated`

even though everything is working and I receive the data from the watch successfully...

I have looked at other questions here but they all have similar solutions:

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191296/wcsession-failing-to-activate/45404265)

[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40707988/wcsession-has-not-been-activated)

Answer (score 0):

Problably `self as? WCSessionDelegate` returns nil because the class doesn't implement the `WCSessionDelegate` protocol. The cast `as? WCSessionDelegate` should not be necessary. You need to make your class conform to the protocol (as seen in Solution 2):

```swift
class SomeClass: WCSessionDelegate {

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I added neccessary functions after conforming my class and now it works!